# OpenCV Cuda calcOpticalFlowBM

Tags: c++, opencv3.0, opticalflow

I am trying to calculate and display opticalFlowBM but having serious troubles. I am using Cuda 7.5 and OpenCV 3.0.0.
I was trying to rewrite it to 3.0.0.
[Sizes of input arguments do not match in cvcalcopticalflowbm opencv 2.4.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21794539/sizes-of-input-arguments-do-not-macth-in-cvcalcopticalflowbm-opencv-2-4-7)
My code (`imgA` and `imgB` are `Mats` read from `VideoCapture // cap.read(ImgA)`):

```
            cvtColor(imgA,imgA,COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
            cvtColor(imgB,imgB,COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
            CvSize size = imgA.size();
            CvSize velsize = CvSize(size.width,size.height);
            size.width/=BS;
            size.height/=BS;
            //result=Mat(size,IPL_DEPTH_8U);
            //result=Scalar(255,255,255);

            Mat velx,vely;
            velx=Mat(velsize,IPL_DEPTH_32F);
            vely=Mat(velsize,IPL_DEPTH_32F);
            GpuMat imgAA;
            imgAA.upload(imgA);
            GpuMat imgBB;

            cvtColor(imgAA,imgAA,COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
            cvtColor(imgBB,imgBB,COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
            imgBB.upload(imgB);
            GpuMat velxx;
            velxx.upload(velx);
            GpuMat velyy;
            velyy.upload(vely);
            GpuMat buffor;
            calcOpticalFlowBM(imgBB,imgAA,cvSize(BS,BS),cvSize(1,1),cvSize(1,1),0,velxx,velyy,buffor);
            Mat abc(imgAA);
            namedWindow("abc");
            imshow("abc",imgAA);
```

But keep getting error:

> OpenCV Error: The function/feature is not implemented (You
>   should explicitly call download method for cuda::GpuMat
>   object) in getMat,file
>   /home/pentaquark/Pulpit/opencv/opencv-3.0.0-
>   alpha/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 1193
>   terminate called after throwing an instance of 
>   'cv::Exception'what():
>   /home/pentaquark/Pulpit/opencv/opencv-3.0.0-
>   alpha/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:1193: error: (-213) You 
>   should explicitly call download method for cuda::GpuMat 
>   object in function getMat

Could anyone help me?